# How to identify second occurance of a value in a column then for that same row but different column map value to something else?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I am working with and I would like to identify the second instance of a particular value in a column, and then map a value in a different column for that same row. An example might be easiest:

```
col1     col2     
 'a'      's'
 'b'      's'
 'f'      's'
 'g'      's'
 'b'      's'
 'l'      's'
```

The above is a short example of the dataframe(s) that I am working with, so I would like to identify the second occurance of `'b'` and for that row map `col2` to `'p'`.

So the output would be:

```
col1     col2     
 'a'      's'
 'b'      's'
 'f'      's'
 'g'      's'
 'b'      'p'
 'l'      's'
```

I am quite new to dataframes so no existing code to work with I'm afraid. I should mention that there IS NO INDEXING for this dataframe, so `iloc` cannot be used, otherwise it would be trivial.

Comment: whats happens if `b` are 3 times? need `1,2,3` ?

Comment: Sorry, I miswrote the values for `col2`. No need for anything more than 2 times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with two masks (equality to "b" and (`&`) [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) to identify the second "b"):

```
# is the row a "b"?
m1 = df['col1'].eq('b')

# is the value duplicated? (i.e. a second "b")
m2 = df['col1'].duplicated()

# if both match, then update
df.loc[m1&m2, 'col2'] = 'p'
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2
0    a    s
1    b    s
2    f    s
3    g    s
4    b    p
5    l    s
```

Intermediates:

```
  col1 col2     m1     m2  m1&m2
0    a    s  False  False  False
1    b    s   True  False  False
2    f    s  False  False  False
3    g    s  False  False  False
4    b    p   True   True   True
5    l    s  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) chained by `&` for bitwise `AND` with compare value by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and pass to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - here all duplicated values without first are converted to `p`:

```
df.loc[df['col1'].eq('b') & df['col1'].duplicated(), 'col2'] = 'p'
```

Or chain [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for compare second value by compare `1` (python count from `0`):

```
m =  df['col1'].eq('b')
df.loc[m & df[m].groupby('col1').cumcount().eq(1), 'col2'] = 'p'
```

Difference of solutions are if 3 or more values `b`:

```
m =  df['col1'].eq('b')
df.loc[m & df[m].groupby('col1').cumcount().eq(1), 'col3'] = 'p'

df.loc[df['col1'].eq('b') & df['col1'].duplicated(), 'col4'] = 'p'

print (df)
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    a    s  NaN  NaN
1    b    s  NaN  NaN
2    f    s  NaN  NaN
3    g    s  NaN  NaN
4    b    s    p    p
5    l    s  NaN  NaN
6    b    s  NaN    p
```

Comment: Ahh my apologies, `col2` are strings! Sorry! Let me correct it in my quesiton.